# как в django шаблоне отборазить день недели

Tags: django, дата

проблема в том что при выводе в шаблон дня недели

```
{{ value|date:"w" }}
```

у меня воскресенье отображается как 0, а я бы хотел каноничную 7. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если в модели одна/две даты, то можно просто создать вычисляемое свойство:

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def isoweekday(self):
        return self.some_date.isoweekday()
```

Но если удобнее работать с фильтром, то нужно [создать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) собственный:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def isoweekday(date):
    return date.isoweekday()
```

Comment: елси по первому способу пойти , то что тогда нужно передать в шаблон , у меня попрежнему отображается 0

Comment: просто укажите новое свойство, а фильтр уберите.

Comment: да спасибо, помогло))